# How can I split and prepend text?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this in C#:

`string a = "A|B|C|D"`

I want to split this string on the pipe character and prepend some text to each entry. Currently, I am doing a split like this:

`string[] result = a.Split('|')`

But because the string array is of a fixed size, I need to create a new array and copy the prepended result using a for loop. Is there a Linq way or a one-liner to achieve this instead of writing a for loop? In Python, I would have done a one-liner for loop:

`newresult = ["Prepend string " + x for x in result]`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to be easy enough, if you say want to join it back too:

`string.Join(" , ", devices.Select(s => "PREFIX = " + s).ToArray());`

Answer (score 2):

```
var newResult = a.Split('|').Select(x => "Prepend string " + x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to create a new array, but first the Linq method is to use the `.Select` operator:

```
stirng[] result = a.Split('|').Select(x => "Prepend string " + x).ToArray();
```

That said, you could also just edit the array inline (i.e. no need for a new array):

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) 
    result[i] = "Prepend string " + result[i];
```